# Remove and set aside elements of vectors within a list that don't exist in another vector

Tags: r

I'm trying to form arguments for use in the `reshape()` function.  I have a vector of column names, some of which should be merged by `reshape()` because they share the same letter at the end:

```
> v <- c("x","da","db","ea","eb","ec","fb")
```

Most of these columns are comprised of a combination of `pre` and `post` characters.  `pre` will be the `timevar` argument and `post` will be the `v.names` argument in `reshape()`.  They are defined as:

```
> pre <- c("d","e","f")
> post <- c("a","b","c")
```

I have organized the problem this way since there are a variable number of columns I will have to perform this on for different files.  By parsing the column names like this, I'm sure I can do this with an algorithm rather than a manual hack.

My desired output is a list of vectors that only include elements of `v` that share the same `post` letter.  The intention is to use these as the `varying` parameter in `reshape()`:

```
> desired_lov
$a
[1] "da" "ea"

$b
[1] "db" "eb" "fb"
```

And in addition, I would like to keep track of which elements are missing from `desired_lov` which still exist in the original `v` vector.  The intention is to use these as the `idvar` parameter in `reshape()`:

```
> desired_idh
[1] "x" "ec"
```

With all that given, someone helped me to build a list of vectors with possible column names with those prefixes and postfixes.  Each vector in this list is named after an element in `post`, and I believe this is important in order for this to work with `reshape()` since it will merge those columns in each vector under a common name:

```
> lov <- Map(function(x) paste0(pre,x),post)
> lov
$a
[1] "da" "ea" "fa"

$b
[1] "db" "eb" "fb"

$c
[1] "dc" "ec" "fc"
```

Except this builds more names from those combinations than actually exist in `v`.  So I would like to keep track of which names in `v` do not exist in `lov`, for which I've tried:

```
> idh <- NULL
> Map(function(x) idh <- paste(idh,lov[[x]][lov[[x]] %in% v]),1:length(lov))
[[1]]
[1] " da" " ea"

[[2]]
[1] " db" " eb" " fb"

[[3]]
[1] " ec"

> idh
NULL
```

Except apparently I'm not succeeding in modifying the `idh` variable using `Map()`

For the next step (after I figure out the bit immediately above), in order to strip out the elements of `lov` that don't match `v`, I've tried:

```
>  Map(function(x) lov[[x]] <- lov[[x]][lov[[x]] %in% v],1:length(lov))
[[1]]
[1] "da" "ea"

[[2]]
[1] "db" "eb" "fb"

[[3]]
[1] "ec"

> lov
$a
[1] "da" "ea" "fa"

$b
[1] "db" "eb" "fb"

$c
[1] "dc" "ec" "fc"
```

Which gives me promising output (I would need to remove all vectors from that list that have length < 2 since I'm only looking for duplicated columns based on their second characters), but once again it failed to actually modify `lov` by removing the elements I was trying to remove.

I've tried searching, but all I keep finding are ways to remove elements of vectors.  This seems to be a much different problem since I'm trying to remove elements from multiple vectors embedded in a list while trying to preserve the vector names in that list.

Edit: I do know about `x` ahead of time, so I can manually exclude it where needed.  But I don't know that `c` is a unique postfix ahead of time (in this particular example), so it needs to be determined within the script.

Comment: In your initial vector, there are some elements with `c` as the end character.  So, you wanted to remove `x` and `c` and then `split` up the vector based on the last character.  You may use `grep/split/substr` to get the desired output. i.e. `v1 <- v[!grepl('\\bx\\b|c$', v)]; split(v1, substr(v1, 2,2))`

Comment: @akrun I don't think OP wants to explicitly exclude 'x' and 'c'. They want code that identifies 'x' and 'c' based on the rule that they do not share a terminal character with any other string in the vector.

Comment: @akrun That's pretty cool, but I don't know about `c` being a unique postfix ahead of time (I do, however know about `x` ahead of time).  That part needs to be deduced in the program, which is why I've structured things this way.

Comment: @plafort Sorry, I didn't read the full post.  Just giving some ideas

Comment: @Shawn If you know the `substrings` that needs to be matched we can match it and remove the rest instead of matching `c` and `x`

Comment: @akrun I'm not sure I follow your meaning.  Suffice it to say that `v` `pre` and `post` are already pre-defined for purposes of this problem, so we can use those resources  to deduce the desired result.

Comment: @Shawn will the 'post' values ever be in 'pre' also? Or are they mutually exclusive?

Comment: In actuality, `pre` and `post` are quite long strings (words separated by underscores or decimals).  So they may share bits and pieces here and there but they would never be identical as a whole.  In fact, `pre` values always have decimals inside while `post` values never do.

Comment: Could you provide examples of a few actual pre and post strings?

Comment: Pre: `"192.168.10.2_card02_port01" "192.168.10.2_card3_port2"` and Post: `"state" "line_speed" "bits_sent"` and v: `"elapsed_time" "192.168.10.2_card02_port01_state" "192.168.10.2_card02_port01_line_speed" "192.168.10.2_card02_port01_bits_sent" "192.168.10.2_card3_port2_state"` etc

Comment: Thx, this helps. And one or two `v` values to compare it to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77803/discussion-between-shawn-and-plafort).

Comment: Your description is `My desired output is a list of vectors that only include elements of v that share the same post letter. `  So, I don't understand why `ec` is not included as `c` is also in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
freq <- lapply(Map(function(x) grep(x, v), post), length)
index <- Map(function(x) grep(x, v), names(freq)[freq>1])
lapply(index, function(x) v[x])
$a
[1] "da" "ea"

$b
[1] "db" "eb" "fb"
```

and

```
v[-unlist(index)]
[1] "x"  "ec"
```

## Data

```
v <- c("x","da","db","ea","eb","ec","fb")
pre <- c("d","e","f")
post <- c("a","b","c")
```